# CloudFlare DNS + jwilder/nginx-proxy error 500

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, cloudflare, jwilder-nginx-proxy

Today I put my current domaine under the CloudFlare DNS.
[dns records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJyF3.png)

On my server, I currently use the jWilder/reverse-proxy
And for other subdomains or main domaines I use Apache2 or Nginx v1.22.

Everything is used under Docker containers.

docker-compose of the reverse proxy :

```yaml
version: '2'

networks:
    webproxy:
        driver: bridge

services:
    nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - /etc/nginx/certs
            - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
            - /usr/share/nginx/html
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
            - ./logs/error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        networks:
            - webproxy
        environment:
            - TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY=true

    nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
        image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - /etc/nginx/certs
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        volumes_from:
            - nginx-proxy
```

nginx reverse-proxy configuration :

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_max_body_size 20m;
    gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}

daemon off;
```

Website configuration :
docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '2'

networks:
    webproxy:
        external:
            name: main_webproxy

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./html:/var/www/html
            - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=${APP_DOMAINS}
            - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
            - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${APP_DOMAINS}
            - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
        expose:
            - 80
        networks:
            - webproxy
            - default
```

nginx config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen          [::]:80;
        listen          80;

        server_name     _;
        root            /var/www/html;
        index           index.html;

        if ($host ~* ^(www\.)(.+)) {
            set         $app_domain $2;
            rewrite     ^ $scheme://$app_domain$request_uri;
        }
        
        location / {
            try_files   $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }
}
```

.env file:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=website
NGINX_VERSION=1.22
APP_DOMAINS=domain.tld
```

But I got error 500 when I want to visit my website :
[visiting error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIJ6B.png)

Could you please help me to make this reverse proxy works please,
Thanks

Is tried this change, but not working, still 500 error :
Changing CloudFlare SSL to FLEXIBLE or FULL.